# Formatting a parsed String to Long

Tags: java

How do I format a parsed String?

For example:

```
ph = "0412456839";
n = Long.parseLong(ph);
```

When I print n, I get (Without 0):

```
412456839
```

I want to print the same as ph. I could always do

```
System.out.println("0"+n);
```

but is there a way to format it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `java.util.Formatter`

```
System.out.printf("%010d\n", n);

    % 0 10 d
      ^  ^ ^
      |  | decimal
      |  width
      zero-pad
```

If you need the output in a `String` instead of writing to `System.out`, use

```
String s = String.format("%010d", n);
```

Comment: In a Format String you can use `%n` for a system dependent newline (which may be `\n\r`) instead of `\n`

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html). That would allow you to format a number into a string using your own formatting rules. In this case, it is formatting it to be a 10 digit number that includes preceding zeros.

```
String ph = "0412456839";
Long n = Long.parseLong(ph);
String formattedN = new DecimalFormat("0000000000").format(n);
System.out.println(formattedN);
```

if you are using Apache Commons, you can use:

```
   int paddingLength = 10;
   String paddingCharacter = "0";
   StringUtils.leftPad("" + n, paddingLength, paddingCharacter);
```